# How to display the category 1 item into category 2 based on UID in Django Model?

Tags: django, django-models

How to display the category 1 item into category 2 based on `UID` in Django Model?

```
Category_1:
UID Item
1  A
1  B
2  C
2  D
```

expected result:

```
Category_2: 
UID Category_1 Cateogry_1_Des
1   1           A
2.  1.          B
3.  2           c
4.  2.          D
```

Model coding (show all item of category_1 but want to show only item mathcing UID) :

```
Category_2 = models.ForeignKey(
      Category_1,
      verbose_name=_('cat2'),
      related_name='cat2'
  )
```

---

Detail:

```
class cat1(models.Model):
    UID = models.ForeignKey(
        'Did',
        null=True,
        related_name="uuid",
        verbose_name='uuid',
    )
    Item = models.FloatField(
        _('Item'),
        max_length = 150,
        null=True
    )



class cat2(models.Model):
    UID = models.ForeignKey(
        'user.UserProfile',
        null = True,
        related_name = "uuid",
        verbose_name = 'uuid'
    )
    Desc = models.CharField(
        _('desc'),
        max_length = 150
    )
    Cat1 = models.ForeignKey(
        'cat1',
        related_name = "Cat1_item",
        verbose_name = 'Cat1_item'
    )

Table record

Cat1
UID Item  
1   A
2.  B
3.  C

Cat2
UID Des Cat1_item
1.  ..  A
2.  ..  B
1.  ..  A
```

Note: `Cat1_item` of `Cat2` are displayed value based on matching value `cat2.UUID=cat1.UUID`

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want make recursive category model. This code provide you recursive category model with more than 2 depths, if only one category model and field is enough for you.

```
class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
parent = models.ForeignKey(
    'self', 
    null=True, 
    blank=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name='children'
    default=None
)
```

It's will be like:

```
Category: 
UID name        parent
1   category_1  None
2.  category_2  1
3.  category_3  2
4.  category_4  2
5.  category_4  3
```

**EDIT:**
category_1 and category_2 will be show same categories

```
class Category(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class MyModel(models.Model):
  category_1 = models.ForeignKey(Category)
  category_2 = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

Comment: it had more than one field. how to do that ?

Comment: @YUIDDAAI please can you share your model class. Is Category_1 a field or class? it's should be a class for your code.

Comment: Please find the detailed update above for your reference.

Comment: Hi @Yusuf Ulusoy any update ?